# 22.04 gnome control center segmentation fault

Tags: settings, gnome-control-center

After a recent update, I am getting seg fault when opening Settings, gnome control center.  Anyone else having this issue?

Kinda disappointed with linux now, decided to start using linux again after using mac osx because of problems working with stuff outside apple ecosystem.  But ubuntu/linux hasn't been that great either.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center` in the unlikely case any of the files have been damaged. If that doesn't help you could report this as a bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center, if your specific issue hasn't been mentioned yet.

Comment: What's the exact error message you get? (You'll see it if you run `gnome-control-center` from the terminal).

Comment: running from terminal i get a simple message- Segmentation fault

Comment: I tried to reinstall.  that didn't work either.

Comment: oh well.  looks like my minipc doesn't like ubuntu.  will have to try a different distro.