# 22.04 gnome-control-center GLib segmentation fault

Tags: gnome, 22.04, settings, gnome-control-center, gdb

Since updating to 22.04, the settings menu segfaults every time I try to start it. I see some other threads with this issue - one who stopped using ubuntu as a solution, and the other answers did not work. Purging and reinstalling did not work. Changing the repo did not work (only using base repos now)
[link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356955/gnome-control-center-segmentation-faults-when-launched)
[link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416096/22-04-gnome-control-center-segmentation-fault)
[link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187809/pop-theme-causes-gnome-control-center-segmentation-fault)

Here is my error:

```
(gnome-control-center:99164): GLib-CRITICAL **: 06:20:19.572: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm using the following version:
gnome-control-center/jammy-updates,now 1:41.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4 amd64 [installed]

Some output:

```
(No debugging symbols found in gnome-control-center)
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/bin/gnome-control-center 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe9ca7640 (LWP 100558)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe94a6640 (LWP 100559)]

(gnome-control-center:100555): GLib-CRITICAL **: 06:33:32.123: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

Thread 1 "gnome-control-c" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff538e842 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff538e842 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
#1  0x00007ffff53d4599 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
#2  0x00007ffff53932d0 in cogl_renderer_connect () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.20
#3  0x00007ffff5665305 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff568a2b7 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff568a608 in  () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff7c8ca67 in g_option_context_parse () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff568a85a in clutter_init () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff6edee91 in cheese_gtk_init () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese-gtk.so.25
#9  0x00005555555bcbf4 in main ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same error message and backtrace:

The libcogl.so in the backtrace is the OpenGL shared library.

When I ran `glxinfo` and `glxgears` other  (both OpenGL tools installed via: `sudo apt install mesa-utils`) those applications were also failing with errors saying `BadValue`.

```
$ glxinfo
name of display: :0.0
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  150 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  85
  Current serial number in output stream:  86
```

This stack overflow question:
[X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644455/x-error-of-failed-request-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-of-range-for-operatio)

Which linked to this forum post:
[[SOLVED] glxinfo (and other OpenGL apps) fails: BadValue](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1102186-start-0.html)

Suggested adding the user to the `video` group and restarting the X-Server.

```
sudo usermod -a -G video ${USER}
```

I just rebooted my computer after that and all of my OpenGL related issues were resolved at that point.

It's hard to say which piece fixed the problem and another user indicated that they: `sudo apt --fix-broken install` followed by `sudo reboot`. So that may be a valid fix as well.

Comment: I'll accept the answer. After rebooting once or twice, the error went away. I assume it was an issue with updating without rebooting that caused it...

Comment: I feel that from an architectural point of view, a settings application should not be so tightly coupled with the graphic subsystem or a graphics driver. If one of the internal menus (or views) of the control center depends on the availability of the graphics subsystem, then it would be fine to disable that. But it seems wired that we cannot configure things like keyboard, mice or network, just because the graphics driver is not functioning correctly. I would expect that the control center opens and gives me detailed feedback on whats wrong, rather then just crashing with a segfault.